# How to create boxplot for some of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I have two Column in excel. I import it to matlab and I create boxplot for them.
I use `boxplot` function:

```
boxplot(BasePay,JobTitle)
```

now I want create boxplot for some value of `JobTitle` for example `JobTitle1` and `JobTitle2`. These is my data:

```
Job Title   Base Pay
JobTitle1   486927.08
JobTitle1   461785.8
JobTitle2   523782.43
JobTitle4   388849.77
JobTitle2   380452.08
JobTitle1   450053.76
JobTitle2   546416.52
JobTitle3   384411.2
JobTitle4   353637.71
JobTitle4   311209.74
JobTitle3   355242.48
JobTitle2   359855.85
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a little more. Have you already plotted plotboxes for the two columns? if so, is your question about plotting only one plotbox?

Comment: Apparently you understand how to use `boxplot`. So what did you try that didn't work? Also create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it should be understood what you actually are dealing with

Comment: @hammadian   I want craete boxplot for 'BasePay' and some value of 'JobTitle' not all of value

Comment: How do you choose which values to plot? if, for example, you want only the first 10 values of each variable you can type `boxplot(BasePay(1:10),JobTitle(1:10))`

Comment: @EBH Job Title Base Pay
JobTitle1 486927.08
JobTitle1 461785.8
JobTitle2 523782.43
JobTitle4 388849.77
JobTitle2 380452.08
JobTitle1 450053.76
JobTitle2 546416.52
JobTitle3 384411.2
JobTitle4 353637.71
JobTitle4 311209.74
JobTitle3 355242.48
JobTitle2 359855.85
 these is my data, I want create boxplot only for 'JobTitle1' and 'JobTitle2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you hold this data, but assuming a cell array for `JobTitle` and a vector for `BasePay`, you can write this:

```
boxplot(BasePay(strcmp(JobTitle,'JobTitle1') | strcmp(JobTitle,'JobTitle2')));
```

if you want to view the several boxplots you better do this:

```
grp = strcmp(JobTitle,'JobTitle1') | strcmp(JobTitle,'JobTitle2');
boxplot(BasePay,grp);
bp = gca;
bp.XTickLabel = {'all other','JobTitle1&2'};
```

[image: boxplot1]

or, if you want to plot only `JobTitle1` and `JobTitle2` but separately, you can write:

```
boxplot(BasePay(grp),JobTitle(grp));
```

using the `grp` variable from above, and with no need to set the labels.

[image: boxplot]

Comment: when I write top code, instead of 'JobTitle1' and 'JobTitle2' in xlabel writed '0' and '1'. are you now what sould I do?